# Enable/Disable Touch Screen on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Is there any way of disabling / enabling the touch events in a certain activity
without disabling certain buttons. like if the phone is "frozen" on a certain activity page for limited time?
I need that the user wont be able to go back on page, slide out or any other events.

Is it possible? (I'm using android studio, java)

Thanks in advance!
Any answer would help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.
Actually there is no special function to make it.

To make it, you can make a full screen button with transparent background.
And you will define a function of the button.
Of course, it will be an empty function.
Well, you can do nothing on the screen.

and then you can hide or visible the button according to your necessary.